Questions about classifying hyperkahler ALE orbifolds
Kronheimer classified all smooth hyperkahler ALE 4-manifolds. In  his paper, he constructed, unsing hyperkahler qutient, a complete family of hyperkahler ALEs for each finite group $\Gamma<\mathrm{SU}(2)$ at infinity. More precisely, he constructed first a hyperkahler moment map for a Lie group action $G$ on a hyperkahler manifold $M$:
$$
\mu_{\mathbb{H}}: M \to \mathfrak{g}^* \otimes \mathbb{R}^3
$$
where $\mathfrak{g}$ denote the Lie algebra of $G$. To applying hyperkahler quotient, we need to take an element $\zeta$ in $Z\otimes \mathbb{R}^3$, where $Z$ is the dual of the center of $\mathfrak{g}$, and then take quotient $X_{\zeta} := \mu_{\mathbb{H}}^{-1}(\zeta) / G$. Of course, $X_{\zeta}$ may not be smooth. But the smooth part of $X_{\zeta}$ admits a hyperkahler structure, hence we could say it's a hyperkahler orbifold (actually I don't know if this is a good definition).
Moreover, he showed that $Z\otimes \mathbb{R}^3$ can be identified with $\mathfrak{h}\otimes\mathbb{R}^3 $, where $\mathfrak{h}$ is the Cartan algebra associated with $\Gamma$ via McKay correspondence. And set
$$
\left(\mathfrak{h}\otimes\mathbb{R}^3\right)^\circ := \mathfrak{h}\otimes\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \bigcup_{\theta\in\Phi}\left( \mathrm{Ker}\,\theta\,\,\otimes \mathbb{R}^3\right)
$$
where $\Phi$ is the root system associated with $\mathfrak{h}$. Then Kronheimer showed $X_{\zeta}$ is smooth if and only if $\zeta\in\left(\mathfrak{h}\otimes\mathbb{R}^3\right)^\circ$.
Therefore, Kronheimer also constructed a family of hyperkahler ALE orbifolds with parameter space
$$
\bigcup_{\theta\in\Phi}\left( \mathrm{Ker}\,\theta\,\,\otimes \mathbb{R}^3\right)
$$
Question: Does this family of hyperkahler ALE orbifolds is a complete family of hyperkahler ALE orbifolds ? i.e. any hyperkahler ALE orbifold with $\Gamma$ at infinity is isomorphic to $X_{\zeta}$ for some $\zeta\in\bigcup_{\theta\in\Phi}\left( \mathrm{Ker}\,\theta\,\,\otimes \mathbb{R}^3\right)$ ? (I didn't find any reference about this)
Some trial: For the simplest case $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, it seems that the only hyperkahler orbifold metric on it can only be the flat metric on $\left(\mathbb{C}^2\setminus 0 \right)/\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ (not be proved !)
